# Why do I need reputation to comment?

Tags: bug, comments

[image]

This kind of confuses me.  In order to reply to a post/answer/thread, a new user, need not do anything other then create and account.  However, if someone comments to that post, the new user must have 50 **reputation points** to reply to someone who commented on their personal answer?  So new users are effectively blocked from productive debate/problem solving concepts.

**What exactly is this actually preventing?**  Spammers can post new threads and make basic reply on anyone's question, but they cannot reply to a reply? Who is out there responding to spammers in the first place?  I personally just ignore them, but this requirement makes no sense to me.  I am trying to communicated with another user on a question, but I am block from talking to them.

At the same time I am repulsed by the concept that the only way to communicate with well anyone is by fishing for imaginary kewl points, which are only obtained by distracting from other questions with popular circular-logic answers that I have no investment in. I could not even find an appropriated tag for this message and it would not let me make one without 300 points.  Is this system intentionally designed to discouraged user from participating in this site?

**All this requirement does is successfully stops people from communicating/clarifying their questions and answers.**  It is based on popular responses, not what is fact or truth. I find this disrespectful and counterproductive to concept of the platform. It generally leads people to believe their "Karma" is authority, while placing undue restrictions of individuals interested in participating in the platform.

Comment: For reference, [here is the comment everywhere privileges page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Is this a question about how to use the site, a feature request, or something else? It isn’t clear that is being asked here.

Comment: Site systems = I can only commit to threads I have created.  I can apparently reply to any thread, but I receive a messages that says I cannot commit on someone else's commit to my reply, because I do not have enough points.  This cannot be how it was intended, as it prevents communication and discourages new users from using the site.  I am reading a message that say I need 5 points just to answer my question.  Why is that a restriction?  It makes no sense for new users to have to make fluff statements for up votes, until they have the reputation to use the site properly.

Comment: @JoshuaGawain It's worth noting that we don't have "threads", because this site **is not a forum**. We are not here for discussion. We are here to answer questions and save those answers in a way that makes it easier for other people to find them later, so they don't have to ask the same question.

Comment: In case this is a bug, please [edit] to add a screenshot of the error you're getting while trying to comment on your own answer. Like everyone says, this shouldn't be happening, so there's either a problem with the system or with how you're trying to comment (e.g., trying to add a comment to an answer that's not yours).

Comment: I’ve gone ahead and added the bug tag since you say you cannot comment on your own post, which would be a bug. As laurel mentioned, a screen shot of the message it gives you when you try would be helpful.

Comment: Relevant from Meta Stack Exchange: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173)

Answer (score 9):

1. Questions and Answers have no requirements. They are the basic ways to interact with the site, and everyone can do them (well, everyone except those who have been banned).
2. The requirement you’re referring to applies to comments. Comments are used in a particular way here; the goal of the 50-point requirement is to give users time to learn the system before using it. They are intentionally low-value and intended to be fairly unimportant. Comments are also—by far—the most common vehicle for venting anger or frustration or whatever with personal attacks or other inappropriate behavior. Since comments do not bump questions, they would also be a tempting target for spammers, who could comment on old questions and go unnoticed. The requirement limits some of that.
3. The 50-point requirement is waived for commenting on various things relating to your own Q&A. Here, it seems you may have run into a bug. I am not 100% sure where the line is supposed to be, but based on documentation it does seem like you should be able to comment on that answer.

   **However**, it should be noted that even if you can, it may not be true that you should. Generally speaking, we want you to respond to comments by editing the Question or Answer, or by ignoring them if you disagree and do not want to edit. Either way, once you are not going to take further action on the comment, it no longer serves a purpose and moderators will routinely delete such comments. If there is a comment you know you are done with (either because you did it or because you are not going to), you can flag it as No Longer Necessary and mods will typically delete it.

   The end-goal is a clean answer with no comments that just best reflects the position of the author (and whose votes reflect the position of the community). Comments are supposed to be primarily between the commenter and the author; nothing of importance to the wider audience should live there, because we want readers to be able to get all the information they need *without* reading through a whole conversation. Comments that are not serving the purpose of improving the question or answer, especially those that become conversation that overshadows the question or answer, will be deleted or migrated by moderators.

   And since this is an unusual use of posting functionality—that can seem superficially similar to replies as in a discussion thread—the comment functionality is slightly gated to try and help new users learn their idiosyncracies before they start to comment.
4. Getting 50 points does not require interacting with 50+ questions or answers. An upvote on a question or answer is worth 10 points, so you need 5 upvotes total to get it (there are other activities that also earn points, and potentially fewer than 10 at a time, but those are largely irrelevant to new users). Many new users get that score with a single question or answer.

Comment: Whether it is low hanging fruit or not it stops users from communicating.  As a new user I can reply to a post that is years old but I cannot comment on a comment.  How is Replying to an old post less of an effect then a comment on the same post?

Comment: @JoshuaGawain Questions are valuable! They attract answers. Answers are valuable! They're the whole reason the site exists. Comments are **not** valuable. They don't contribute to the site except in the most indirect manner, by (possibly) prompting another user to improve existing questions or answers. And as KRyan pointed out in point #2, comments are high *risk*; they're an ideal vector for spam & personal attacks. Comments are restricted because they're much *less* likely to benefit the site and much *more* likely to **harm** the site.

Comment: Yet new users are banned from clarifying their own statements via comments. There are a great many complicated (multi-layered) answers. A wall of text does not serve anyone as it is likely to be ignored even if correct, but an answer that summarizes an idea followed by a string of comments that allow readers to go through the motions can be a valuable tool. (Just one example)

I do not believe that comments are any more or less valuable to the process then the actual answers. There are already delay systems that prevent users from spam posting. This pt system is unnecessarily redundant.

Comment: @JoshuaGawain “Yet new users are banned from clarifying their own statements via comments.” No, they’re not. You can comment on your own posts and answer to your own questions.

Comment: I am still getting a 50pt requirement to respond to a comment for an Answer "I made."  If that is not how it is suppose to be then there is something wrong with the system.

Comment: @JoshuaGawain Which post are you unable to comment on that you think you should be able to?

Comment: @JoshuaGawain That’s correct: if you get a comment on your Answer, you should respond by _editing your Answer_. Comments are the way they are because _the system does not want back-and-forth arguments_. Either you agree with the comment and improve your post as it suggests, or you don’t and you ignore it—or if you really don’t want to leave the comment there, you can flag it as No Longer Necessary to indicate you aren’t going to take the recommended action, and mods will remove it.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Tried posting a URL with formatting, something is stopping the comment with the URL?  Looking into this system now. **KRyan** = A lot of answers are a conversation.  Blanket statement work for a lot, but without going through the steps of how a concept reaches an answer, then answers become novels that no one bothers to reads. Often a short answer invokes the reader to question the concept, and comments resolve those questions without resorting to an answer that is so long that it would have deferred the reader from even making the attempt.  Comments have value to the process.

Comment: @JoshuaGawain This is not the place for back-and-forth conversation. The system is literally designed to try and prevent it. Those rules are relaxed some here on Meta, but on Main we should not be talking like we are here. If we did, even with all the privileges in the system, moderators would delete or migrate the conversation. The system really **only** wants to do Q&A. If you object to that, this may not be the place for you.

Comment: It matters not because I will never earn the Make a Wish points to meet any of these restrictions.  I have no interest to fish for likes and I find it disrespectful to conversation in general.  They system is broken because it is based on popular response, not what is or is not true.

Comment: @JoshuaGawain The site **is not for conversation**. If the system makes conversation hard then *mission accomplished*. The site is for people to ask questions and get answers.

Comment: @KRyan I thought for sure that people could comment on their own posts. As in, if I post an answer as a 1-rep user, I can leave comments on my own answer. I just can't leave comments on _another person's_ answer. [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) mentions that “All users may comment on their own posts”. Joshua should be able to reply to our comments on his answer in its comment section.

Comment: @doppelgreener I was also under the impression that it worked that way.

Comment: @JoshuaGawain I see you're having trouble grating against our reputation system, but the system is based on peer review. Others vote on your answer based on whether they feel it's truthful and accurate. It's not a popularity contest, it _is_ in fact about what is true. People are downvoting your answer because they feel it is not true and accurate, and lacks the support to demonstrate that accuracy. An answer that is overly speculative and not well cited may be downvoted. We gate things behind reputation so that people can figure out our system a bit at a time, and don't crash and burn.

Comment: @doppelgreener I might be misremembering.

Comment: Joshua should be able to comment in their own answer posts, see what I've done here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/209670/62294

Comment: @doppelgreener Quite the contrary.  Statistics on most sites that utilize "Karma" find that truth is the least appealing way to generate "Karma."  Thus it becomes less about Peer Review and more about popular opinion.  I just got done talking to someone who claims to have 12 accounts on this site so they can up and down vote whatever they want.  They offered to help and I asked them not to.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Well I am not able to comment on my answer, and now the question becomes, is the answer being down voted for it's content or accuracy or is it being downvoted because of my response to you about this broken Karma system?  Is that the point behind the karma system?  For votes to be based on information not pertaining to the question or answer?  Hum this system is working great.*

Comment: @JoshuaGawain I explained in a couple of comments why I downvoted, and I imagine the other downvotes are for similar reasons.

Comment: @JoshuaGawain Happy to help.

Comment: @JoshuaGawain Could you post a screenshot of the error you're getting? You should be able to comment on your own answer, and if you can't that's a bug.

Comment: @ObliviousSage It appears I need 5 reputation points to post an answer in this section.  I tried putting the screenshot in the comment but it just bounces it to another screen.  I am attempting to figure out if I can upload a screenshot into comments now.

Comment: @JoshuaGawain You can upload images to your question.

Comment: @doppelgreener good point. TY

Comment: I hope you all can see the image.  I can add an additional answer to other user's questions, but that seems counter intuitive and misleading.  Thus far, the only question/thread/whatever I have been able to add comments on is this question.  I assume it is because I authored this question.  Everywhere else the button is grayed out and that little blue notification appears.

Comment: What we're seeing in that screenshot looks like a genuine bug. You should be able to comment on your own answer just fine; something's broken.

Comment: @JoshuaGawain Note that maintaining multiple accounts for the purpose of evading voting limits is a violation of the [Inauthentic usage policy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/conduct/inauthentic-usage) and could be reported.  For some perspective, I've had some pretty [unpopular answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/194645/23547) and [questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/175279/23547), but I've never had twelve downvotes on anything.

Comment: @Kirt while I agree, there is little that can be effectively done about it.  It is a problem with all karma/reputation systems.  Reporting the individual will only reduce their misbehavior by one, likely disposable, account.  If they made 12 accounts then they will they will continue to do so even as a few of them are banned, and it is an effective way of become an adversary against someone already cheating the system.  These systems are not peer review they are popularity, and fake popularity counts.  Such behavior would not be appealing to some if the system did not exist.

Comment: @JoshuaGawain Your statements contradict the experience of literally every person who finds these sites useful. They also contradict the entire premise of the sites—if the voting doesn’t work, the sites don’t work, and I guess we should shut it all down. Except, of course, we’re not doing that, because somehow, the voting actually does in fact produce useful value to a very large number of people—suggesting that your assertions that it does not do so are incorrect. Anyway, the long and short of it is, this site is one of a large network, and we have no control over this. It won’t change.

Comment: (“It” being the concept of voting to promote answers; any actual bugs we can hope will be fixed, of course.)

Answer (score 8):

### Users can always comment on their own posts

The 50 rep limit on comments is only towards commenting on other users' posts. Even users with one rep are able to comment on their own questions, and on answers their questions have received.

Regarding spammers, this limitation prevents them from posting spam on any old post; instead it becomes limited to questions and answers which will then push the question to the recent feed, where it'll be seen by users and removed (raise yer flags!).

Also about 50+ topics: since each upvote gives 10 rep, getting a total of 50 is not a high bar. A single decent question or answer will earn that.

Comment: Whether it is low hanging fruit or not it stops users from communicating. As a new user I can reply to a post that is years old but I cannot comment on my own reply? How is Replying to an old post less of an effect then a comment to a reply on the same post?

Comment: @JoshuaGawain I'm simply not following you. You can comment on your own posts, and answer (but not comment) on old questions.

Comment: I don't know how to respond to that.  History = I made a reply to an old post/question and someone misunderstood the point to "My Reply."  So, they added a comment to "My Reply," but I am restricted from responding to their comment to "My Reply," based on an arbitrary point system that forces people to fish for likes before they can communicate like adults.  It blows my mind that this is a thing that merits conversation.

Comment: @JoshuaGawain You're definitely supposed to be able to reply to comments on your own posts. You may find [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173) over on the networks main meta useful

Comment: Well that is a better response then I have received from other people.  Comments should have no effect on the priority of a question, so restricting them just does not make sense to me.  I keep getting a response that "it works because they say it works," which feels dismissive and demeaning.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

### You *should* be able to comment on your own answer post.

I just tested this with a new account on the same question you answered:

[image]

Comment: I am no web specialist, but as this site is dependent on cookies, it is very possible that because you were originally log on an account that met the Karma points thresholds, that the cookie relayed the threshold and voided the restriction on the new account.  Again I am not a web designer, for whatever reason I am prevented from posting a comment on the answer that I posted.

Comment: @JoshuaGawain That’s not how it works, and I created that account on a different machine that doesn’t use stack exchange anyway.

Comment: @JoshuaGawain Editing others’ posts is an entirely normal part of curating content on our site. See here for more details: [Why did another user edit my post?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11202/62294)